# Receiving data from the prestashop database passing through the "store"

Tags: c#, database, connection, prestashop

I'm trying to find the best solution to my problem. I have an API in C# that is going to get the tables that exist in the prestashop webservice, but now I need to make a more specific Sql call for example "INSERT", so it is no longer possible to use the prestashop webservice.

There are several options, such as making the direct connection of my API to the database, but I did not want to go around because there are some problems with external accesses to where the database is hosted.

Create a module in the prestashop that connects to the database.

There is also in the prestashop in the for advanced meters->database the possibility of creating queries, but I don't know how to access them through my C# API and I think it is only allowed to do SELECT

If you know other solutions, please tell me, or which of these options would be the best, thank you!